# How to access Struts 2 variables in jQuery

Tags: java, jquery, jsp, struts2

I'm trying to get access to a Struts 2 property via jQuery.

My Common.js file looks like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    alert("<s:property value='myVariable'/>");
});
```

When I load my view, it alerts the whole string instead of resolving the Struts 2 variable.  I'm guessing there's just some syntax tricks that I'm missing... any help would be appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: This will work only if your script is placed directly in JSP with Struts2 taglib definition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should place the script to the JSP

```
<head>
  <script type="text/JavaScript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
      alert(<s:property value="myVariable"/>);
    });
  </script> 
</head>
```

you cannot use struts or other JSP tags inside the js files. It doesn't compile by the server. However, you could use a function in JSP that call those scripts by passing parameters to it.

```
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="<s:url value='/js/Common.js'/>"></script>         
  <script type="text/JavaScript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
      alertMyVariable(<s:property value="myVariable"/>);
    });
  </script> 
</head>
```

In js:

```
function alertMyVariable(myVariable) {
  alert(myVariable);
}
```